# layout xml block="" usage - exam question

Tags: layout, blocks, xml, frontend, certification

A couple of weeks ago I failed my frontend developer exam by 1 point, Tomorrow I am going to retake.

I have a question which I want to be sure about. In the exam I had some xml snippets and I had to pick the right one. A lot of times I saw snippets containing `block="block_name"`. I never saw this in any layout xml file ever so I thought this is bad code maybe to trick me. This kind of snippet containing `block=` popped up several times which started to confuse me.

I searched everywhere but couldn't find an example. Do you guys now any usage for this or is it to trick me?

**Example**

```
<action method="insert" block="contactForm"/>
```

Can someone clarify this? Can `block=` be used in some xml code or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it is never used in core layout XML, the `block` parameter of `action` entities is a shorthand which is perfectly valid and allows you to use actions outside of a `reference` or `block` scope. For example:

```
<default>
    <reference name="contactForm">
        <action method="someMethod"><params /></action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

has the same effect as:

```
<default>
    <action method="someMethod" block="contactForm"><params /></action>
</default>
```

Note that I said "has the same effect as" rather than "is the same as"; I believe there may be an ordering difference between the two. Would have to check to confirm.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying Ben, i'll delete my answer if FROSIT can un-accept and mark yours as the accepted answer?

Comment: Up to you @JoshCarter. It's an obscure detail for sure.

Comment: Hmm, true @benmarks, just thinking for the benefit of any future exam takers looking for help.

Comment: Hi benmarks, thanks for correcting this. Because there's like almost none documentation about this i think it's important people taking the exam should now about this. Today i got these questions again and the options without block= didn't make any sense. I just tested this and it can be used by for example method="setTemplate" block="my_block". I passed eventually with a score to be proud of :) thanks Stackers!

Answer (score 2):

I believe that there is no usage for block= in Magentos xml, action, template, name, type, method, as, before and after are a few of the main usages for Magento. There is no need for a block= as you are defining the block type in the type="" value.

Also when using the above method to insert a block you would use the following syntax, notice how block has its own node:

```
<action method="insert">
     <block>contactForm</block>
</action>
```

Insert can also only be used to insert a block tha thas previously been unset eg. before the above example you would have:

```
<action method="unsetChild">
     <name>contactForm</name>
</action>
```

Hope this helps, and good luck on your exam!

Josh

Comment: Thanks for confirming and the examples. Magento did a great job at tricking me the last time haha. When seeing so much bad examples at the exam you get confused with what was bad code and not. I hope i'll pass :)

Comment: No worries, good luck again!

Comment: This is incorrect.